# Permutation-Arranging Bride and Groom

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can a photographer at a wedding arrange six people in a row, including the bride and groom, if the bride is positioned somewhere to the left of the groom?

---

Assuming the bride is at the furthest to the left spot:

Why is the first line 5!

Assuming she's at the 2nd spot:

Why is it $4*4!$

If someone could explain that would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this is to observe that there are $6!=720$ permutations of the $6$ people.  In half of these, the bride is to the right of the groom, and in half of them, the bride is to the left of the groom.

So the answer is $\dfrac{6!}{2}=360.$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**Mitchell Spector** has given by far the nicest solution; I’ll answer your specific questions about a more brute force approach. If the bride is in the leftmost spot, the remaining $5$ people can be lined up in any order to the right of her. There are $5!$ possible permutations of $5$ people, so there are $5!$ arrangements with the bride at the left end. If she is in the second spot, we can choose any one of the four people who are *not* the groom for the first spot; that leaves $4$ people to fill the four spots to the right of her, and they can be arranged in any of $4!$ different orders. There are therefore $4\cdot4!$ ways to arrange the men if the bride is in the second position.

If we continue with this reasoning, we see that if she is in the third position, we can pick any of the $4$ other people who are not the groom to fill the first spot, and after we’ve done this, we can pick any of the $3$ remaining people other than the groom to fill the second spot (since the groom can’t go in either of those spots). That leaves $3$ people to be lined up to the right of her; there are $3!$ possible arrangements of those $3$ people, so there are altogether $4\cdot3\cdot3!$ arrangements with the bride in the third position.

Similarly, there are $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot2!$ arrangements with the bride in the fourth position and $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1!$ arrangements with her in the fifth position. It’s impossible for her to be in the sixth position, as in that case the groom would have to be on the wrong side, so the total number of arrangements is

$$\begin{align*}
5!&+4\cdot4!+4\cdot3\cdot3!+4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot2!+4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1!\\
&=120+96+72+48+24\\
&=360\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the thorough explanation.

Comment: @MeroFuruya: You’re welcome.